# What’s wrong with this proof that the set of natural numbers is uncountable?

Tags: analysis

Suppose the set is countable, and can be arranged in a sequence. Then we construct a number whose nth digit is different than the nth digit of the nth number in the sequence, which means that it is not in the sequence.

Comment: Such a "number" is an infinite string of characters and is not a number.

Comment: @DavidKraemer Then what makes the difference between a number and a string?

Comment: There is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the set of all *finite* strings of characters in the alphabet $\{0,\dots, 9\}$. The "number" you constructed is not in this set, so you haven't shown that $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable.

Comment: I'll give you such a sequence:  $(1, 2, 3, 4,\cdots)$.  Now we construct the number $2$.  Its $n$th digit is different from the $n$th number in the sequence, where $n=1$.  What has been proved here?

Comment: In other words, you are not guaranteed that each $n$th number in your list has as many as $n$ digits, hence your proof fails. If you want to give each natural number an infinite preamble of zeros, and count digits from right-to-left, you will need to create a “number” that contains an infinite number of nonzero digits (which is what the first comment says) because you will need to change an infinite number of zeros to nonzeros.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your proof has been at least partially inspired by Cantor's diagonal argument, so I think I can see where your confusion stems from. In case you need a refresher, say we want to prove that the set of real numbers in $(0, 1)$ is uncountable. Suppose it isn't, then we can enumerate the set $\left\{s_0, s_1, s_2, ... \right\}$

Each $r \in (0, 1)$ can be represented in base 10 as $(0.a_0a_1a_2a_3...)_{10}$ where $a_i \in \left\{1,2,...,9\right\}$. We know that $r$ can be uniquely represented in base 2  as $(0.b_0b_1b_2b_3...)_2, \forall {b} \in \left\{0, 1\right\}$

From then on the proof is similar to what you proposed: We consider $s$ to be a number when the ith digit of it's binary representation is different to the ith digit of the binary representation of $s_i$. Since $s \in (0, 1)$ and $\nexists i, \ s_i = s \ $we can then conclude that $(0, 1)$ is uncountable.

Why doesn't the same argument work for $\mathbb N$? For one, we have no idea how we can even represent the members of $\mathbb N$. For example $(2)_{10} = (10)_2 = (.10000...)2^2$. But $(4)_{10} = (100)_2 = (0.100000...)2^3$, so you see that we can't uniquely define a number in the same way we did before.

I think at this point you can see why your argument fails: the nth digit isn't guaranteed to exist because you don't have a clear idea what the "nth digit" really is.

Comment: I think the problem with the argument is that the hypothetical “number” is not a number, since it has indefinitely many digits. We can define nth digit as the first non zero digit in base 10 counting from right to left.

Comment: Again, how can you guarantee that the nth digit exists? You have to set additional restrictions (e.g $s_i$ has at least $i$ digits in its decimal representation) but then there won't exist a bijective mapping between $S$ and $N$